# What is the typical voltage of power distribution in rural North America?

Tags: mains, power-engineering

I mean the electrical utility power that connects to the transformer outside of the home or other buildings.  i.e. what is the primary winding voltage of the transformer having 220 VAC center-tap secondary?

i have heard as high as 13 kV, but that seems kinda high.  isn't it more like 4 kV?

Comment: It varies but around here it's 7.2kV. That would be a 12,470 wye.

Comment: High enough not to go near it, end of...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

12470V (delta)/7200V (Wye)

13200V (delta)/7620V (Wye)

24940V (delta)/14400V (Wye)

34500V (delta)/19920V (Wye)

source is bulletin 1724-D-114 USDA rural distribution system

Comment: i know what Y and Δ is and i know about \$\sqrt{3}\$, but in the expression: *"12470Y/7200"*, what is the 7200?  because i would expect the Delta voltage to be \$\sqrt{3}\$ times the Wye voltage.

Comment: I would also expect some 'V' symbols in there.

Comment: i think *volts* is assumed.  unless i see *"kV"* in there.

Comment: You are correct, I believe they/I have a typo in the "Y/"order. Fixing now.

Comment: Volts is correct, thought about the whole ',' vs '.' nomenclature left unambiguous (though it would be one heck of a wire at 12.47V :-)

Comment: thanks.  i guess, without asking the power company, that i will not know which one of the 4 options.  the first two are, to me, roughly equivalent.  like the difference between 110 VAC and 120 VAC.  also, in rural areas i have seen, there often was only one phase, not three.  sometimes i noticed single wire, earth return (that **really** seems *iffy* to me).

Comment: I think the only way would be to look at the length of the insulators, I'm sure you can find some standards/manufacturers on the web for guidance.  I've also seen some safety demos for firefighters/responders on youtube with info.

Comment: See [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/71614/guessing-power-line-voltage-from-the-number-of-disc-insulator) for guessing the voltage based on the visible bushings.

Comment: NPSN-Line-Post-Catalog.pdf at www.newellporcelain.com has info on sheet 6(pdf)

Comment: but @davidmneedham , that's really friggin' high voltage.  my question is more about distribution than transmission.

Comment: Heh, if it wasn't dark already I'd go out and snap some picture with my camera to check- I can do that tommorrow, we have all sorts of stuff around here.

Comment: See the link @isdi posted. The 10 kV per ring rule is still useful for estimating. It would let you differentiate between 13.2 kV and 34.5 kV systems.